# zk: how to notify a listener when a zk component is destroyed / detached

Tags: java, zk

is there a possibility to notify a listener when a ZK component is destroyed or detached?

I want different composer of components communicate via an event queue. In order to do this I subscribe listeners for these components to the event queue. Now I need to know when a component or its composer is destroyed in order to unsubscribe its listener.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can implement [UiLifeCycle](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/util/UiLifeCycle.html).

Documentation: http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Configuration_Reference/zk.xml/The_listener_Element/The_org.zkoss.zk.ui.util.UiLifeCycle_interface